# 3 table Join - optimisation suggestions?

Tags: mysql, join

Rather new to MySQL queries beyond simple Inserts and Selects, so if this seems utterly basic I apologise in advance.

I have a database with a few many-to-many relationships and am attempting to build a JOIN query across 3 tables. It's the first big tables / big query I've attempted to write so am going by what the tutorials I read. The query returns all the correct values, however, seems to ran rather slow (averaging .25 of a second but peaking around .7 on the localhost).

I'm wondering if anyone has any advice on how to make it more efficient? I've played around with indexes (new to those as well) and that seems to have little measurable effect - the real time killer here seems to be the ORDER BY statements. Unfortunately I can't get my head around optimising those despite trawling Stack Overflow and trying a whole host of things.

This is the query in concern:

```
SELECT a.d_id, cs_id, blg_id, d_name, d_slug, ct_id, a.cc_id
FROM collection a
JOIN designers b
ON a.d_id = b.d_id
JOIN designer2type c
ON a.cc_id = c.cc_id
WHERE cs_id = '3'
ORDER BY d_name, ct_id ASC
```

I've tried a few alternatives (copied some tutorials on sub queries that took much longer to run and also the following which has a similar average but a much higher max:

```
SELECT collection.d_id, cs_id, blg_id, d_name, d_slug, collection.cc_id, c_url FROM collection, designers, c_image WHERE cs_id = '3' AND c_image.ci_id = collection.ci_id AND collection.d_id = designers.d_id ORDER BY d_name ASC
```

This is the Explain with  || representing column breaks:

```
id || select_type || table || type || possible_keys || key || key_len || ref || rows || Extra
1 || SIMPLE || a || ref || PRIMARY,d_id,cs_id || cs_id || 4 || const || 8403 || Using temporary; Using filesort
1 || SIMPLE || b || eq_ref || PRIMARY || PRIMARY || 4 || test.a.d_id || 1    
1 || SIMPLE || c || ref || cc_id || cc_id || 4 || test.a.cc_id || 1
```

And these are the table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `collection` (
`cc_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`d_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
`cs_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
`cfw_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
`c_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
`ci_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
`cg_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
`blg_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cc_id`),
KEY `d_id` (`d_id`),
KEY `cs_id` (`cs_id`),
KEY `cfw_id` (`cfw_id`),
KEY `c_id` (`c_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `designers` (
`d_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`d_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`d_slug` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`d_id`),
KEY `d_name` (`d_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=52782 ;

CREATE TABLE `c_designer2type` (
`cd2t_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cc_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
`ct_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
`cd2t_desc` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cd2t_id`),
KEY `cc_id` (`cc_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=57545 ;
```

I'm not sure if this is a query problem, an index problem, or a table structure problem. Or perhaps not a problem at all, though maxing near a second on a localhost with no other load and only a medium amount of rows seems high in my head. Either way, nothing about this project is in use so anything can be changed if needed.

If anyone has any thoughts / advice on where I might be going wrong in the quest it'll be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks, Tania

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an index on "cc_id" on the  c_designer2type table, currently the query must scan the entire table several times to do the join.

Also it might be worth considering an index on "cs_id" as this is your main selection criteria, in the current set up every row in the 'collection' table is examined to see if it matches. This is only worth doing if there is a reasonable number of values for 'cs_id'. If you only have 1,2 & 3 its not really worth it.